# How can I use multisig / split keys using My Wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, multi-signature

I was sure that [My Wallet](http://blockchain.info/wallet) supported multisig, but I can't seem to find it now.

How can three users of My Wallet create an address that is only spendable if at least two of them cooperate? Or is this not implemented yet? If so, when is it due?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/what-gui-clients-support-multisig-transactions

Comment: FYI, I asked that this feature be returned - https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1247889#msg1247889

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the latest info](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1196203#msg1196203) I have seen from Ben who runs blockchain.info.

> Question: The escrow function seems to be gone. Will it return?
>   https://blockchain.info/wallet/escrow?
>
> Ben: The escrow feature was removed because not enough people were using it. I think maybe it was just too confusing/not well documented enough.

I did not see any info on if/when it will return.

Comment: Thanks. I specifically wasn't referring to any escrow, just to multisig - but I may have imagined it. So the answer is - right now there's no real multisig support in blockchain.info.

Comment: Escrow is a great idea, and will probably encourage a new class of users to adopt Bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

I think you will start to see more support for this as we attract a larger support base. The alternative is often trusting an anonymous escrow on a forum which isn't so appealing.
Given support for escrow is essentially built in to the blockchain protocol, it seems natural to integrate it with a wallet.