# What GUI clients support multisig transactions?

Tags: client, multi-signature

Are there any major current UI wallets (desktop/mobile/web) that support creating / spending multisig transactions?

Comment: See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/how-can-i-use-multisig-split-keys-using-my-wallet

Comment: ...and http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/11563

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do some Bitcoin wallets fail to support sending to multi-signature addresses?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/do-some-bitcoin-wallets-fail-to-support-sending-to-multi-signature-addresses)

Comment: i think that keyhotee supports creating multisig transactions

Answer (score 2):

Armory is a client for advanced users that has support for multisignature 
https://bitcoinarmory.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [DarkWallet wiki](https://wiki.unsystem.net/en/index.php/DarkWallet/Alpha#Multisig) states that DarkWallet supports "creating and spending multisig funds". However, the text there further specifies that "at the moment spending and communicating the funds is quite manual, transactions have to be copy pasted from one user to another".

An answer on [How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/how-can-i-create-a-multi-signature-2-of-3-transaction), features code to generate and spend 2-of-3 transactions presumably with Bitcoin-Core, as Gavin created the script.